# How do I compare dates using Eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I run this code,

```
$entry_id = Entry::where(function($q)use($intern,$input){
                    $q->where('interna_id',$intern['id']);
                    $q->where('created_at','=','2015-06-06');
                })->first(['id']);
```

it gives

```
select `id` from `entries` where (`interna_id` = 1 and `created_at` = 2015-06-06) limit 1
```

and as you can see, the date is not enclosed in `''`. This causes a problem and MySQL will not be able to find the record. For example, if I add the `''`, like so,

```
select `id` from `entries` where (`interna_id` = 1 and `created_at` = '2015-06-06') limit 1
```

The query is able to retrieve the correct record.

Note:The created_at is using Date format, not DateTime

Answer (score 0):

`created_at` is of type date for laravel. It uses the Carbon package and expects such an object. You would have to do something like:

```
$entry_id = Entry::where(function($q)use($intern,$input){
                    $q->where('interna_id',$intern['id']);
                    $q->where('created_at','=', Carbon::parse('2015-06-06'));
                })->first(['id']);
```

please note you have to include the library on the page using;

use Carbon\Carbon;`enter code here`

Alternatively you could use `DB::raw` for the date as well (untested):

```
$entry_id = Entry::where(function($q)use($intern,$input){
                    $q->where('interna_id',$intern['id']);
                    $q->where('created_at','=', \DB::raw('2015-06-06'));
                })->first(['id']);
```

Comment: how about if it's a variable? something like `Carbon::parse($variable)` doesn't work. I've also tried the raw version too.

Comment: if $variable is a string with some kind of date format, that should be no issue

Comment: It does work only if I use timestamps but please note I'm using Date type... which is `$table->date('created_at')` instead of `$table->timestamps()` in my migration...

Comment: It doesn't matter. First off check your database it probably is of type timestamp. And if it's a date field, the insert/update will convert the full datetime into a date.